# how can I react-bootstrap change the color of the tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I want to change the color of the tabs used in react-bootstrap.
but when I change the style it goes for the content and not the tabs. How can I do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Specify a class on the `<Tabs className="myClass">` component. To modify the color of the tabs your CSS is going to look a little hacky but I haven't found a better way to do this:

```
.myClass ul > li > a {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
}
```

You will notice that this does not cover hover and inactive states so there is a little bit more work for you to do, but this should be enough to head you in the right direction.

[Working example at CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yMmywz)

Comment: This is still basically the correct answer but as of 2020 the pattern seems to be:

.myClass > a {/* your styles here */}

Comment: for me the working variant is `.nav-tabs .nav-item.nav-link.active` - in this way the active tab will have the needed colored background

Answer (score 4):

In React-Bootstrap V5 What worked for me is the CSS code below without specifying any className on the `<Tabs>` element.

```css
.nav-tabs .nav-link {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  color: #FFFFFF !important;
  border-top: none !important;
  border-left: none !important;
  border-right: none !important;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active {
  border-bottom: solid 4px white !important;
}
```

Comment: !Important is bad , is there anyway to do via scss?

Answer (score 1):

In react-bootstrap v4 the Tab component has a property called **tabClassName** (https://react-bootstrap-v4.netlify.app/components/tabs/#tab-props). With its help you cann pass in a class and define CSS which will override the default classes:

```
# in css file:

.coloredTab {
  background-color: red;
}

# in jsx file:
<Tab ... tabClassName={classes.coloredTab} />
```

Didn't check the newest v5 though. Might even got better.